# Use of "massively" in this specific sentence

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, sentence

Instead of using *massively* in the following sentence, what else can I use?

> I am **massively** running out of time now!

I have tried "terribly", "horribly", "incredibly", "unbelievably", and "almost". The first words seem strange to me because this is the first time I have heard of them. The two later are fine since I heard native people use them before. But still, I would like to know your opinions over how they are correctly used both in writing and speaking cases.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "I am rapidly running out of time" - it's more accurate and descriptive IMHO since it expresses speed and motion, which is what the sentence is trying to convey.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just assume everything you hear native speakers saying is good grammar. This example is nearly nonsense. The adverb *massively* doesn't go together with *running out* of something. You could be "quickly running out of time" or have an "urgant need for more time". You could also have a "massive amount of work to do in a small amount of time".

Answer (score 1):

"Massively" here can have the meaning here of 'to a great degree.' It can also have the [meaning of completely, totally.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/massively)

Thus, in your example, it would mean that the fellow speaking was running out of time to a great degree, or, he that was very, very late.

Or, applying the second meaning, it could mean that the fellow speaking was totally, absolutely late.

But, I think the first definition applies better to this case.